# How to properly import a package from sub-directory in Golang?

Tags: go

I am pretty new to Golang and trying to make a simple REST api app work.

Initially, everything was all fine since I had all code in the same directory under the `main` package.

But, now I am at a stage where I need to start refactoring code into sub-directories and packages. Unfortunately, I have not been able to compile the app successfully.

My `GOPATH` is set to: `~/.workspace`
The current app is at: `~/.workspace/src/gitlab.com/myapp/api-auth`

This is how my current code organization is:

[image]

Here is my `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "github.com/justinas/alice"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"

    "gitlab.com/myapp/api-auth/middlewares"
)

func main() {
    privateKey := []byte(strings.Replace(os.Getenv("JWT_KEY"), "\\n", "\n", -1))

    conn, err := mgo.Dial(os.Getenv("MONGO_CONN"))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()
    conn.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    ctx := appContext{
        conn.DB(os.Getenv("MONGO_DB")),
        privateKey,
    }

    err = ctx.db.C("users").EnsureIndex(mgo.Index{
        Key:        []string{"username"},
        Unique:     true,
        Background: true,
        Sparse:     false,
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    commonHandlers := alice.New(LoggingHandler, context.ClearHandler, RecoveryHandler, AcceptHandler, ContentTypeHandler)

    router := NewRouter()
    router.Post("/users", commonHandlers.Append(BodyParserHandler(UserResource{})).ThenFunc(ctx.userCreationHandler))
    router.Post("/sessions", commonHandlers.Append(BodyParserHandler(UserResource{})).ThenFunc(ctx.sessionCreationHandler))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}

type appContext struct {
    db         *mgo.Database
    privateKey []byte
}
```

Here is one of the middleware `accept.go` (Rest of the middleware are constructed similarly)

```
package middlewares

import "net/http"

// AcceptHandler ensures proper accept headers in requests
func AcceptHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Header.Get("Accept") != "application/vnd.api+json" {
            writeError(w, errNotAcceptable)
            return
        }

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }

    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

This is the error I get when I run `go build` from root of my app.

```
# gitlab.com/utiliti.es/api-auth
./main.go:11: imported and not used: "gitlab.com/myapp/api-auth/middlewares"
./main.go:42: undefined: LoggingHandler
./main.go:42: undefined: RecoveryHandler
./main.go:42: undefined: AcceptHandler
./main.go:42: undefined: ContentTypeHandler
./main.go:45: undefined: BodyParserHandler
./main.go:46: undefined: BodyParserHandler
```

Comment: You reference symbols (functions, variables, types) from other packages by name spacing with that package name - e.g. `middlewares.AcceptHandler`. This is why they are seemingly undefined and middlewares is 'unused'.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Qualified identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers)
>
> A qualified identifier is an identifier qualified with a package name
>   prefix. Both the package name and the identifier must not be blank.
>
> ```
> QualifiedIdent = PackageName "." identifier .
> ```
>
> A qualified identifier accesses an identifier in a different package,
>   which must be imported. The identifier must be exported and declared
>   in the package block of that package.
>
> ```
> math.Sin  // denotes the Sin function in package math
> ```
>
> [Import declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)
>
> An import declaration states that the source file containing the declaration depends on functionality of the imported package (§Program
>   initialization and execution) and enables access to exported
>   identifiers of that package. The import names an identifier
>   (PackageName) to be used for access and an ImportPath that specifies
>   the package to be imported.
>
> ```
>     ImportDecl       = "import" ( ImportSpec | "(" { ImportSpec ";" } ")" ) .
>     ImportSpec       = [ "." | PackageName ] ImportPath .
>     ImportPath       = string_lit .
> ```
>
> The PackageName is used in qualified identifiers to access exported identifiers of the package within the importing source file.
>   It is declared in the file block. If the PackageName is omitted, it
>   defaults to the identifier specified in the package clause of the
>   imported package. If an explicit period (.) appears instead of a name,
>   all the package's exported identifiers declared in that package's
>   package block will be declared in the importing source file's file
>   block and must be accessed without a qualifier.
>
> The interpretation of the ImportPath is implementation-dependent but it is typically a substring of the full file name of the compiled
>   package and may be relative to a repository of installed packages.
>
> Implementation restriction: A compiler may restrict ImportPaths to non-empty strings using only characters belonging to Unicode's L, M,
>   N, P, and S general categories (the Graphic characters without spaces)
>   and may also exclude the characters !"#$%&'()*,:;<=>?[]^`{|} and the
>   Unicode replacement character U+FFFD.
>
> Assume we have compiled a package containing the package clause package math, which exports function Sin, and installed the compiled
>   package in the file identified by "lib/math". This table illustrates
>   how Sin is accessed in files that import the package after the various
>   types of import declaration.
>
> ```
>     Import declaration          Local name of Sin
>
>     import   "lib/math"         math.Sin
>     import m "lib/math"         m.Sin
>     import . "lib/math"         Sin
> ```
>
> An import declaration declares a dependency relation between the importing and imported package. It is illegal for a package to import
>   itself, directly or indirectly, or to directly import a package
>   without referring to any of its exported identifiers. To import a
>   package solely for its side-effects (initialization), use the blank
>   identifier as explicit package name:
>
> ```
>     import _ "lib/math"
> ```

The error

```
./main.go:11: imported and not used: "gitlab.com/myapp/api-auth/middlewares"
```

says that you have no uses of package `middlewares` in package `main`, which is true.

The error

```
./main.go:42: undefined: AcceptHandler
```

says that you haven't defined `AcceptHandler` in package `main`, which is true.

"A qualified identifier is an identifier qualified with a package name prefix. A qualified identifier accesses an identifier in a different package, which must be imported."

For example, in package `main`, use the qualified identifier `middlewares.AcceptHandler`, which is a use of import `"gitlab.com/myapp/api-auth/middlewares"`.

Comment: very helpful, in-depth explanation to someone new to the language.

Comment: my brain melted

Comment: absolutly would not work for me until I created the root folder "/src", that particular folder name "/src" is the magic that made it work. I made "/src/foo/bar.go" and put "package baz" in bar.go and then my root file /main.go could import {module name from root go.mod}/src/foo and could call baz.DoStuff()